# Error in v-on handler: "FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function CollectionReference.doc()

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that deletes an item from db

```
deleteMovie: function (id) {
                if (id !== null && id !== undefined) {
                    db.collection("movies").doc(id).delete().then(function () {
                        console.log('Document successfully deleted')
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        this.error = error
                    })
                } else {
                    this.error = 'Invalid ID'
                }
            }
```

on button

Delete
When i try to delete i get the error

**Error in v-on handler: "FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: a custom MouseEvent object"**

Comment: Can you show the entire code of your Vue.js Component please?

Answer (score 1):

The error is fairly clear.  It's saying that the `id` argument you passed to `db.collection("movies").doc(id)` is expected to be a string, but you passed something else (a MouseEvent).  You're going to have to figure how to get the needed document ID from that MouseEvent object.  There's not enough information here for anyone to be able to tell you exactly what to do.  But it should be clear that you can only pass a non-empty string to `doc()`.